# How to render javascript templates in Play 2?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Play newbie here.

In the Play documentation it is claimed that Play templates can be any text-based format. How does it work if instead of an html template I want to use a javascript template or a pure text template?

In Rails, I can have different views (templates) for different formats. For instance I can have a `people/index.html.erb` that uses a partial called `_list.html.erb` which looks like this:

```
<h1>People</h1>
<ul id="people">
  <%= render "list" %>
</ul>
```

I could then have a `people/index.js.erb` that uses the same partial and looks like this:

```
$('#people').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("list")) %>');
```

If the client needs to render the entire page, it can send a request which accepts an html document, and the app will serve the html view. If OTOH the client only needs to update part of the page, it can send a request which accepts a script, and the app will serve the js view. This is very clever IMHO, and I would like to do something similar in Play.

What I naïvely tried was to create a template named `index.scala.js` and then calling `Ok(views.js.index("Hello world"))`. That doesn't work unfortunately. I get an error `object js is not a member of package views`.

Is there an idiomatic way to accomplish this in Play 2?

Comment: Try by just naming your file `index.scala.html` instead of `index.scala.js`.